# What is the least number of (fixed) parameters I can ask for, when calculating area of a triangle of unknown type?

Tags: triangles, area

I need to calculate the area of a triangle, but I don't know, whether it is right angled, isoscele or equilateral.

What parameters do I need to calculate the area of a triangle of unknown type?

Comment: To be a bit witty here, you only need to know one parameter, the area itself is totally sufficient to calculate the area.

Comment: The answers include the SSS and SAS formulas; I wonder if anyone will bother with ASA or SsA (or maybe even both sSA options)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need is the **lengths of each side** of the triangle.

By Heron's Formula, we know for a triangle with sides $a,b,c$, we have

$$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\text{ ,where }s=\frac{a+b+c}2$$

**Reference:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula

---

**EDIT:**

In response to suggestion by @Hurkyl , I now add the case of ASA and SsA.

---

***(ASA)***

With a known side $c$ and its neighbouring angles $\alpha,\beta$, we have:

$$A=\frac{c^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{2\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}$$

**Proof:**

Let $\alpha,\beta,\theta$ be the corresponding angles of sides $a,b,c$ respectively, we have

$$\theta=\pi-\alpha-\beta\implies\sin\theta=\sin{(\pi-\alpha-\beta)}=\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}$$

By Sine Law,

$$\frac c{{\sin{(\pi-\alpha-\beta)}}}=\frac a{\sin\alpha}=\frac b{\sin\beta}$$

So $a=\frac{c\sin\alpha}{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}$, $b=\frac{c\sin\beta}{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
A&=\frac12ab\sin\theta\\&=\frac12\cdot{\frac{c\sin\alpha}{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}}\cdot\frac{c\sin\beta}{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}\cdot\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}\\&=\frac{c^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{2\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}
\end{align}

---

***(SsA)***

With 2 known sides $b,c$ and $\beta$, the corresponding angle of $b$, we have:

$$A=\frac12 c\sin\beta[\sqrt{1-(\frac{c\sin\beta}b)^2}+c\cos\beta]$$

**Proof:**

By Sine Law:

$$\frac b{\sin\beta}=\frac c{\sin\theta}$$

$$\sin\theta=\frac{c\sin\beta}b, \cos\theta=\sqrt{1-(\frac{c\sin\beta}b)^2}$$

By Cosine Law,

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$$
$$c^2-b^2+b^2\cos^2\theta=a^2-2ab\cos\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta$$
$$c^2-b^2\sin^2\theta=(a-b\cos\theta)^2$$
$$a=b\cos\theta+\sqrt{c^2-b^2\sin^2\theta}=b\cos\theta+c\cos\beta$$

So
\begin{align}
A&=\frac12ab\sin\theta\\&=\frac12(b\cos\theta+c\cos\beta)(b)\cdot\frac{c\sin\beta}b\\&=\frac12 c\sin\beta[\sqrt{1-(\frac{c\sin\beta}b)^2}+c\cos\beta]
\end{align}

Comment: hkmather802: Thank you so much. That solved the problem

Answer (score 6):

The area of a triangle can also be calculated as $\frac12 rp$, where $r$ is the radius of the incircle and $p$ is the perimeter.

Comment: That's a sneaky one. You just break it down into 3 triangles of height r whose bases sum to p. It seems a very good way to calculate the radius of the incircle, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is another general formula for the area of a triangle: $A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle enclosed by the sides of length $a$ and $b$. This is simply a generalisation of $A=\frac{1}{2}bh$ when the concept of *height* doesn't correspond to a side of the triangle.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of answers to this question--all* of them will involve knowing *3* parameters about the triangle; the formula you use depends on which 3 you know.

So far we've seen Heron's formula if you know three sides and the law of cosines approach if you know two sides and an angle (note that also subsumes the formula for a right triangle).

I'll add the [shoelace formula](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pJRYk-31Mpk) if you know the coordinates $(x_i,y_i), i=1,\ldots,3$ of the vertices:

$$\frac{1}{2}|x_1y_2 + x_2y_3 + x_3y_1-y_1x_2-y_2x_3-y_3x_1|$$

*not exactly, see comment below

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be three parameters - e.g. you can have one side and the perpendicular distance to the opposite vertex, or the perimeter and the radius of the incircle, or (as @mlk points out) it could be just one, the area itself :)

Comment: @psmears good point, thanks--you need 3 parameters to uniquely identify the triangle, but can get away with less if all you want is its area.

Answer (score 0):

1. If all the sides say $a$, $b$ & $c$ of a triangle are known then the area of the triangle is calculated as follows  $$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ Where, $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\text{semi perimeter}$
2. If we know any two sides & the angle included between them then the area of triangle is given as follows $$A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin A=\frac{1}{2}ac\sin B$$